# Using php inside Javascript in a .php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display all the files in a folder using PHP.

```
    var fn=<?php $dir = "folder/*";
    foreach(glob($dir) as $file)  
    {  
    echo $file.'</br>';  
    }
    ?>
    console.log(fn);
```

The console displays the output as *undefined*. I am new to using PHP in Javascript, and I am sure I am missing something important here, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the .php file in the same directory as the folder you are pulling files from?

Comment: Maybe you needs quotes around list of files you are assigning to fn?

Comment: Better show us what do you want to achieve if it was written with the pure JS.

Comment: @AbraCadaver is right, you are missing the quotes. Check this example: [Repl](https://repl.it/repls/IroncladQuirkyNanotechnology)

Comment: It is in the same folder and I tried doing "/folder/*", but output still is undefined.

Comment: @lakdee Can you supply your folder structure? In my example it is working having the folder in the same level of the PHP file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AbraCadaver is right, you are missing quotes when you are assigning the value to the variable `fn`.

```
<?php
  $dir = "folder/*";
  foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {  
    $result .= $file . '</br>';
  }
?>

<script>
  var fn = "<?php echo $result; ?>"; // <- Error was here
  console.log(fn);
</script>
```

Note, that generating JavaScript by joining strings can be tricky and buggy, sometimes better option is passing your data as a JSON object into JS and then working with it with JS:

```php
<?php
$dir = "folder/*";
$arr = [];
foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
    $arr[] = $file;
}
$jsonObj = json_encode($arr);
?>

...

<script>
    var fn = <?php echo $jsonObj; ?>; // <- in this case DO NOT wrap JSON object with quotes!

    fn.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(item, index) {
        console.log(index, item);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, if @AbraCadaver answered in comments why are you parroting that here? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what to do and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Please show your suggested code here in the answer instead of linking it to the external sites. Until it's fixed will remain downvoted,

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I did it because it he didn't created the answer (because maybe he didn't tested or wasn't sure), yet I credited him and if he wanted, he could have posted his answer. Didn't know that this was against the rules or even unethical, was just trying to help the OP giving him an example.

Comment: Then post your example code in your answer, not on some remote site that might disappear. I am trying to help you give better and more useful answers.

Comment: @besior, that was my next step. Doing it right now.

Comment: Writing valid answer should be a one-step process. Always

Comment: @besior, you are correct, my apologies and thank you for the feedback. Also thanks to JayBlanchard for the feedback.

Comment: IMHO, outputting it to HTML is unnecessary in the sample and I'd suggest to remove it, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @biesior I agree with you, I removed from the SO code snippet but I left on the external source demo because it is easier to see it in action.